# Function to increase price by 20% only if price is less than $20

Tags: price, wpallimport

I'm wondering if someone can help with a function for WP All Import to increase prices only if the price is less than $20. Perhaps my question is how to set up variables? price1(actual price)?

```
$price1 = "{Cost[1]}";
$price2 = "20"
$price3 = "$price1 + 20%";
function choose_price_to_return ($price1, $price2) {
    if ($price1 < $price2) {
        return $price3;
    } else {
        return $price1;
    }
}
```